# Верстка flex-box: разное расстояние между блоками, блоки скачут

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, flexbox

Столкнулась в верстке с двумя проблемами и не могу разобраться в чем причина.

Первое - блоки скачут и при переносе на следующую строку располагаются на разных расстояниях, хотя изображения одинакового размера.

Второе - как статично разместить внутренний блок с количеством компаний d нижнем правом углу?

```css
.products-inner {
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  align-items: flex-start;
  align-content: center;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

a {
  display: block;
}

.image {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 10px;
}

#c_cnt {
  background-color: #eee;
  width: 50px;
  height: 35px;
  font-size: 18px;
  position: relative;
  top: 80px;
  text-align: center;
  left: 70px;
  top: -40px!important;
  z-index: 1;
}

#c_comp {
  font-size: 10px;
}

.image a {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="products-inner">
  <div class="image">
    <a href="" title="" class="zoom zoom2">
      <img src="" width="120" height="120">
    </a>
    <div id="c_cnt">133
      <div id="c_comp">компании</div>
    </div>
    <a href="" title="">Государственные органы</a>
  </div>

  <div class="image">
    <a href="" title="" class="zoom zoom2">
      <img src="" width="120" height="120">
    </a>
    <div id="c_cnt">3
      <div id="c_comp">компании</div>
    </div>
    <a href="" title="">ЖКХ, ГЖУ, УК</a>
  </div>

  <div class="image">
    <a href="" title="" class="zoom zoom2">
      <img src="" width="120" height="120">
    </a>
    <div id="c_cnt">6
      <div id="c_comp">компании</div>
    </div>
    <a href="" title="">Медицина</a>
  </div>

  <div class="image">
    <a href="" title="" class="zoom zoom2">
      <img src="" width="120" height="120">
    </a>
    <div id="c_cnt">4
      <div id="c_comp">компании</div>
    </div>
    <a href="" title="">Наука и образование</a>
  </div>

  <div class="image">
    <a href="" title="" class="zoom zoom2">
      <img src="" width="120" height="120">
    </a>
    <div id="c_cnt">0
      <div id="c_comp">компании</div>
    </div>
    <a href="" title="">Красота и здоровье</a>
  </div>

  <div class="image">
    <a href="" title="" class="zoom zoom2">
      <img src="" width="120" height="120">
    </a>
    <div id="c_cnt">64
      <div id="c_comp">компании</div>
    </div>
    <a href="" title="">Отдых и развлечения</a>
  </div>

  <div class="image">
    <a href="" title="" class="zoom zoom2">
      <img src="" width="120" height="120">
    </a>
    <div id="c_cnt">96
      <div id="c_comp">компании</div>
    </div>
    <a href="" title="">Магазины и ТЦ</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: По второму пункту не понял. Что значит «статично»?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это то, что вам было нужно?

```css
.products-inner {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.image {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 10px;
  width: 120px;
}
.image .zoom {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}
.image .zoom img {
  vertical-align: top;
}
.c_cnt {
  background-color: #eee;
  width: 50px;
  height: 35px;
  font-size: 18px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 1;
}

.c_comp {
  font-size: 10px;
}

.image a {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="products-inner">
 <div class="image">
  <a href="" title="" class="zoom zoom2">
   <img src="" width="120" height="120">
   <div class="c_cnt">133
    <div class="c_comp">компании</div>
   </div>
  </a>
  <a href="" title="">Государственные органы</a>
 </div>

 <div class="image">
  <a href="" title="" class="zoom zoom2">
   <img src="" width="120" height="120">
   <div class="c_cnt">3
    <div class="c_comp">компании</div>
   </div>
  </a>
  <a href="" title="">ЖКХ, ГЖУ, УК</a>
 </div>

 <div class="image">
  <a href="" title="" class="zoom zoom2">
   <img src="" width="120" height="120">
   <div class="c_cnt">6
    <div class="c_comp">компании</div>
   </div>
  </a>
  <a href="" title="">Медицина</a>
 </div>

 <div class="image">
  <a href="" title="" class="zoom zoom2">
   <img src="" width="120" height="120">
   <div class="c_cnt">4
    <div class="c_comp">компании</div>
   </div>
  </a>
  <a href="" title="">Наука и образование</a>
 </div>

 <div class="image">
  <a href="" title="" class="zoom zoom2">
   <img src="" width="120" height="120">
   <div class="c_cnt">0
    <div class="c_comp">компании</div>
   </div>
  </a>
  <a href="" title="">Красота и здоровье</a>
 </div>

 <div class="image">
  <a href="" title="" class="zoom zoom2">
   <img src="" width="120" height="120">
   <div class="c_cnt">64
    <div class="c_comp">компании</div>
   </div>
  </a>
  <a href="" title="">Отдых и развлечения</a>
 </div>

 <div class="image">
  <a href="" title="" class="zoom zoom2">
   <img src="" width="120" height="120">
   <div class="c_cnt">96
    <div class="c_comp">компании</div>
   </div>
  </a>
  <a href="" title="">Магазины и ТЦ</a>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Да, именно это я имела ввиду! Спасибо большое! Не понимаю, из-за каких свойств у меня не получилось добиться,чтобы блоки себя нормально вели, хотя тоже прописывала ширину .image

Comment: Я там много чего переписал, не только ширину. Но и в CSS всякое, и разметку в HTML. Сравните внимательней.